# Suggested Edit (User who has privileges to approve tag wiki edits)

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Currently I have privileges to approve wiki tag edits in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

**Pre-Requisite**

User should have reputation score more than 5000

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Edit a wiki tag
2. From that moment onward you can see following

[image]

Clicking on that gives

[image]